# Vue.js - как сделать функции, добавленные с новым элементом, независимыми друг от друга

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

Всем привет. 
В коде ниже есть два массива - один со значениями, другой используется для счетчика.
Не могу понять, почему некорректно работают счетчики (надо, чтобы на каждую кнопку они работали независимо).
+ Интересует, как сделать так, чтобы счетчик запускался автоматом, без нажатия кнопки. Те загрузили страницу, есть 3 элемента. И сразу счетчики стали считать.
Если добавить новый, то в нем отсчет начнется с нуля
[Ссылка на фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/VeVeO/jqr0nzte/26/)

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#page',
  data: {
   arr: [1, 2 ,3],
    count: [0, 0 ,0]
  },
  methods: {
   addEll: function() {
     this.arr.push(this.arr.length + 1);
      this.count.push(0);
    },
    incrementio: function(val) {
        interval = setInterval(() => {
        Vue.set(this.count, this.count[val], 0);
        this.count[val]++;
      }, 1000);
     },
  },
  computed: {
   visibleList: function(){
     return this.arr;
    }
  }
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="page">
<button v-on:click="addEll">Добавить элемент</button>
{{ arr }}
{{ count }}
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in visibleList">
        {{item}}
        <button v-on:click="incrementio(index)">Счетчик: {{count[index]}}</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Задавайте вопросы поменьше, с одной проблемой в вопросе, легче будет решать. А по сути вопроса, для начала попробуйте сделать компонент счетчика([например базовый пример в документации](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)) и сделайте несколько независимых счетчиков и напишите что не получается для Вашей задачи.

Answer (score 0):

[Решение на JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VeVeO/1Lcv9nwb/)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#page',
  data: {
    arr: [{
      value: 1,
      counter: 0
    }],
    interval: null
  },
  mounted () {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.arr.map(x => x.counter++);
    }, 1000);
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  },
  methods: {
    addEll () {
      this.arr.push({
        value: this.arr.length + 1,
        counter: 0
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="page">
  <button v-on:click="addEll">Add</button> {{ arr }}
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in arr">
      {{item.value}} Counter: {{item.counter}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```